# How to get the observable value from any component in Angular?

Tags: angular, observable

I have an application protected by login page and I am trying to implement a simple session timer let's just say if the user hasn't refresh or done anything in the app (meaning did not go through OnInit()) the app should kick the user out

Currently I have in my `app component` the following function

```
subscribeTimer: any;
minutes = 0;
seconds = 0;
timeLeft = 12;


ObservableTimer() {
    const source = timer(1000, 1000);
    const abc = source.subscribe(val => {
      if (this.subscribeTimer === 1) {
        abc.unsubscribe();
        this.alertfy.alert('Session Timed Out', 'Your session has been expired!', () => { this.logOut(); }, false);
      }
      this.subscribeTimer = this.timeLeft - val;
      this.minutes = Math.floor(this.subscribeTimer / 60);
      this.seconds = Math.floor(this.subscribeTimer - this.minutes * 60);
    });
  }
```

I am importing `timer` from `rxjs`

Then I am injecting minutes/seconds in my component.html like this

```
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn" style="text-align: right;"><p>Time Left: {{minutes}}:{{seconds}}</p></div>
```

I am currently calling the function `ObservableTimer()` within my `OnInit()` of this `app component` resulting of not subscribing to this observable until I refresh the page when I am already logged in like the following:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
        this.oberserableTimer();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to start the this observable from a different service called `auth.service.ts` this service handles the login and my `app component` can access any function in it because it is injected in the `app component` constructor. In other words when the user login, start the observable in my auth service and let app component subscribe to this observable and read its value and update its html accordingly.

Plus, I want to be able to reset that time from any component, let's say a user did click on something, or navigated to another page. I want to be able to reset the that timer.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Put the timer function / variables in the auth service. Then inject your service into any constructor that you want. You will be able to call the function or use the variables by doing something like `this.service.function()`. You can read up here: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injecting-services

Edit -

Ah, after understanding your use case, I would suggest the following. You don't really want your services to do too much "thinking", if that makes sense. The warning dialog in the code below will open a popup to the user letting them know their session is about to expire.

In app.component.ts:

```
public constructor() {
  //Begins keeping track of the timers
  this.setWarningTimeout();
  this.setLogoutTimeout();
  //If the inactivity reaches the threshold, run these functions
  this.userInactiveWarning.subscribe(() => this.openWarningDialog());
  this.userInactiveLogout.subscribe(() => this.logoutUser());
}

//Sets the warning timer to 25 minutes
private setWarningTimeout() {
  this.userActivityWarning = setTimeout(() => 
  this.userInactiveWarning.next(undefined), 1500000);
}

//Sets the logout timer to 30 minutes
private setLogoutTimeout() {
  this.userActivityLogout = setTimeout(() => 
  this.userInactiveLogout.next(undefined), 1800000);
}

//Listens for mouse movement
//If user moves mouse, then it will reset the timer
@HostListener('window:mousemove') refreshUserState() {
  clearTimeout(this.userActivityWarning);
  clearTimeout(this.userActivityLogout);
  this.setWarningTimeout();
  this.setLogoutTimeout();
}
```

Comment: This is my first project in Angular and I know I did a lot "right" things but I still need to actually put it in the right use.. so if I created a function in the auth service like this StartTimer() {
    const source = timer(1000, 1000);
    const abc = source.subscribe(val => {
      return val;
    });
  }
and then called the function within the service when the login was successful like this:
this.StartTimer();

How can I tell the component to start reading val from the moment of a successful login to update its html?

Comment: Thank you @masu9. I will give it a try

Comment: How can I start this timer when the user login, the auth component (service) is a child of app component

Comment: @Riad I'm not sure how to do it the way you want it. I would suggest only kicking out the user based on certain routes / urls. The `this.logoutUser()` function is what would have this logic. For example, `if(this.router.url !== '/login')`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have a countdown service to do what you want. If you create a countdown service as a singleton, you can access it from any component, in your code, your auth service dispatch an action to countdown service to init the countdown when the user is logged in.

Your component gets the status or properties from the countdown service to get the time left.

This way other components can inject your countdown service and reset the countdown.

An example in order to clarify.

In order to help you with a descriptive way, I wrote a dummy method to create a countdown. You can improve it later.

Note: I am ignoring a lot of code in this example, I only write the important code in order to clarify the solution.

```js
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// This service needs to be a singleton
export class CountdownService {
  private timeleft: number; // in secs

  initCountdown() {
     const timestamp = 999999; // set your timestamp
     // create my timer
     timer(0, 1000)
      .pipe(
        tap(() => {
          // timeleft in secs
          this.timeleft = Math.round(
            (timestamp - Date.now()) / 1000
          );
        }),
        takeWhile(() => this.timeleft > 0) // unsubscribe when timeleft is 0
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  getTimeLeft(): number {
    return this.timeleft;
  }

  reset() {}
}
```

```js
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class AuthService {
  // this behavior subject store the auth state
  private authSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private countdownService: CountdownService) {} // inject my countdown service

  signIn(): void {
    // ... your sign-in logic
    if (loggedIn) {
      // authSubject$ is now true, in order to spread the state
      // now other components can subscribe to the observable
      // to know wha is the auth state
      this.authSubject$.next(true);
    }
  }

  signOut(): void {
    // set false on signing out
    this.authSubject$.next(false);
  }

  isAuth$(): Observable<boolean> {
    // get the auth state as an observable
    return this.authSubject$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

```js
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class ComponentA {
  constructor(private countdownService: CountdownService, private authService: AuthService) {}

  getAuthState() {
    this.authService.isAuth$()
    .pipe(filter((isAuth) => isAuth))
    .subscribe(() => {
      // user is logged in
      this.timeLeft = this.countdownService.getTimeleft();
    });
  }
}
```

```js
export class ComponentB {
  constructor(private countdownService: CountdownService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // on entering page reset countdown
    this.countdownService.reset();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @bjdose for your answer, this is what I had in mind but I am having problem writing the 3 methods based on my original method so they can do what I need. also, when you say this.countdownService.getTimeleft(), aren't you missing the subscribe like that this.countdownService.getTimeleft().subscribe()?

Comment: Oh, I got it. You need to subscribe only if your getTimeleft method is an obervable.

Comment: I edited my answer in order to create a dummy timer and get the time left from any component.

Comment: here you are getting the timeleft only based on a condition.. what I want is more of like a listener.. as soon as the user login, the app component will detect the change and update its html.. in your example, it is based on function getAuthState

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer and add the auth state as an observable, this act as a listener. When user is logged in, component A is listening to it.